# Find part of class name and target it

Tags: jquery

I have a code which basically hides and shows next p after previous one is clicked. The thing is that classes that I want to target change with every product. So how would i go about writing a code that would be universal and would work with all products

https://jsfiddle.net/Legktcwg/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  jQuery('.form-row.form-row-wide.addon-wrap-8-zdjecie').hide();
  jQuery('.form-row.form-row-wide.addon-wrap-8-zdjecie').first().show();

  jQuery('.input-text.addon').on('change', function() {
    jQuery(this).closest("p").next().show();
  });
});
```

In this case I want to target every class but with any numer in place of 8 so 9, 1232, 332 etc.

Comment: How about assigning some additional attribute (class or `data-` attribute) for all these items, then targetting this attribute in your selector instead?

Comment: BTW, it might be a better idea to assign some `.hide`-like class for all those items first, then drop it for the first one. As it stands, there's a flash of all the items, which isn't good UI-wise.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery supports pattern matching selectors, for example to [match an attribute that starts with a value](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) your code should be something like this:

```
jQuery("p[class^='form-row form-row-wide addon-wrap-']").hide();
```

You can also match selectors that [end with something](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/), [that match anywhere](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/), etc.

[Here's a JSFiddle with working code](https://jsfiddle.net/4pkkjhv7/) and a simplified part of your HTML.

Comment: sadly this is not working :( I know you said "something like this" but im a total newb, yesterday I've finished my 1st jQuery tutorial, and what i created is not working as I initented it to :D Anyway thanks for the effort

Comment: sadly it did not, it has to do with the whole plugin, casue when i put that code to work it hides all fields of said plugin, even tho it shouldnt. If u want I can provide you with link to live site so you would better understand what the problem is, if you dont thanks sooo much for taking the time and helping me out :)

Comment: Sounds like a separate question?  AFAICT the code I provided does exactly what you asked for.